# Normalisation of data along with KFold Cross Validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am working on a project of disease prediction where I have to create survival prediction using the given data by applying machine learning classifiers.

Along with the survival prediction I will then have to select important features, features that contribute more to the prediction using different feature selection techniques.

After selecting those features I am going to apply Machine Learning classifiers on those selected features and will check if selected features with ML classifiers yields more accuracy or not than just applying ML classifiers on all the features. Also, I am using K-fold cross validation to split my data into test and training set and using mean accuracy as the measurement.

My questions are:

- Should I / can I normalise my data using Standard Scaler before applying K-fold CV?
- If yes, how can I do the same?

(I apologise in advance if I am unable to frame the question properly, I am new to this platform).

Comment: You should scale data in each CV step. I'm working on [AutoML](https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised) and we apply preprocessing in each cross-validation iteration. Preprocessing information is computed on train data, and then applied to test fold.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is should I/can I normalise my data using Standard Scaler
> before applying K Fold CV?

This could result in data leakage. For each training fold, you'll normalise the data with the statistics (e.g. mean/std) calculated over the training fold and apply these pre-calculated stats to the validation set. So, this is to be repeated for each fold. K-Fold is applied not only to the ML method chosen, but also to pre/post processing code, all of which can be thought of as a pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. If I understood it correctiy, you are referring me to use a pipeline where in each cycle of K Fold CV my training data metrics will be used to fit the standard scaler and will be used to transform my test data. This step using pipepline will be repeated for every fold, hence preventing data leakage?

Comment: You’re welcome @ShubhamKaushik That’s correct.

Answer (score 0):

In case you look for an article and a post of pipelining I answered a similar question once:[Training, saving and distributing the model – what about data the transformations?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/513656/training-saving-and-distributing-the-model-what-about-data-the-transformation/513934#513934)